# Audio files disappeared from S8!

Tags: file-system, samsung-galaxy-s-8

Don't know how long ago the files disappeared or whether it has to do my the Oreo upgrade recently; or using the phone's "fix now" button to delete leftover files; but the audio files that were less than a minute long in length have disappeared from my S8.

I always used Solid File Explorer to search for the files when I wanted to listen to them but today when I searched for the files they are all gone!!!

Freaked out as the files cannot be downloaded again as they were deleted from sites long time ago.

So what caused my files to be deleted? I want to avoid this in the future.

S8 on Oreo

Comment: If you want to avoid it then back stuff up (at least two backups).

Comment: @CmosBattery but why is the "fix now" feature on Oreo deleting files I downloaded to keep?!  Thought it was for garbage files. Figured out that was the cause & have now stopped using that feature.

Comment: I've not lost files from fix now on Samsung devices. Fix now can reset app(s) such as Flipboard (left from home) - suppose if the files were attached to an app in a similar way that fix now could remove them then perhaps that's it.